# Partner Super User Access in Communities

Tags: sharing, customer-community, partner-communities

I've asked this question a number of different ways over the past couple weeks and have yet to find a workable answer so here goes again.

In communities there seems to be a checkbox that says "Enable Partner Super User Access".  According to the documentation, [Super users have access to data owned by other partner users belonging to the same account who have the same role or a role below them in the role hierarchy.](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_partner_super_user_access.htm&language=en_US)

Which sounds great, but what im trying to do is to grant my partners access to all the data created by **Customer Communities** users in the same account.  Will this checkbox do that?  is there another simple way to do this?

Everything i've been trying so far requires me to switch ownership of the data away from the communities user (which prevents them from accessing/editing it without view all/read all access)

Any advice or experience here would be really helpful

Comment: I should be clear, based on my tests this DOES NOT work.  But it feels like it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key to your answer lies in this part of the document you linked in your post:

> Super users have access to data **owned by other partner users** belonging to the same account who have **the same role or a role below them in the role hierarchy**. Super user access applies to cases, leads, custom objects, and opportunities only, but external users have access to these objects only if you exposed them using profiles or sharing and added the tabs to the community during setup.

What the above says it that it **only applies to partner users** who essentially have a limited version of a regular Salesforce License; something which Communities Users do not have. An important detail here is that **Partner Users also have a role in the hierarchy** while **Community Users do not**! Thus, the provision to apply it to a `Portal User` with **the same role or a role below the super user still would not apply**. That's of course because `Community Users are not Partner Users`; one of the initial requirements that was stated.

The avenue to explore may be the last line I've quoted with respect to `"external users have access to these objects only if you exposed them using profiles or sharing and added the tabs to the community during setup."` How you configure this for your objects and the sharing rules you establish (or possibly sharing groups that you create) may ultimately be the most efficient route to solving your issues.

**EDIT**

It's possible to create share rules. Here are links to 2 docs that may be of help to you:  [Sharing Records Owned By High-Volume Community Users](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_sharing_light_users.htm&language=en_US) and [Getting Started With Communities](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf). Both discuss sharing groups and how to set it up for Community users. [HVCP User Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_setting_light_users.htm&language=en_US) is similar.

Comment: I understand that.  I'm asking basically the same essential question I was asking in the other thread.  Is it possible to create share rules for content owned by customer community users.  It seems like the answer is no, that in order to control sharing you have to change the owner first.  Right?

Comment: The answer is yes it's possible to create share rules. Here's 2 docs that may be of help to you: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_sharing_light_users.htm&language=en_US and http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf]. Both discuss sharing groups and how to set it up for Community users. HVCP User Sharing is similar and covered at https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_setting_light_users.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Right but you cant created apex based sharing rules on content owned by Communities users.  Thats the big missing piece.  I wonder if they might add that down the road?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Correct, no APEX sharing for Community Users as you should have seen by now in the docs I located and posted in my answer to your previous question. I think you could potentially use a trigger to add users to a sharing group, but that would be about it. Your idea of changing ownership that you've been considering would be a good alternative as well. I know its not the answer you were looking for, but at least you've got one now. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Its working so far.. not as secure as i would have liked but i think its ok in this case